# Reboot and Select proper boot device after installing a new HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

After installing a HDD in my old pc, I kept getting the reboot and select  proper boot device message. I  installed the drive in my main  PC , that have an ssd and a diff HDD, to check what the problem is and now main PC is getting the same message and won't boot even after removing the new HDD.

What I tried. Use a different cable and different port. I tried using my USB stick with windows installer made using Rufus  but I got  an error "bios legacy boot of wifi only media" that I did not have before.

Manage to get it to work. But when I attempted A fresh install of windows  I noticed that my PC reads my SSD as 0.0mb.
As a temporary solution I, removed the SSD and tried to install Windows on my old Hdd. After the first stage of my istallation and my PC restarts, I got a blue screen "recovery,  your PC couldn't start properly. Error code 0xc0000001.

I  updating the bios and attempted another windows install, and I got the same result

Update: the old PC works now somehow.  But my main PC still doesn't. I manage to borrow an ssd with an already installed os to try. There where two options in the bios boot selection, the SSD name and boot manager (?) Selecting the second one I was able to go to windows. But after rebooting the problem came back

Comment: Are you using the same Windows 10 license on both disks and both set to boot?  That may be the source of your problem.  Remove the hard drive entirely. See if the SSD boots or if you need to reinstall Windows 10 on the SSD.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the old PC is working again, it has its own ssd. I'm starting to think that it's a combination of problems, the new drive is faulty and the old SSD  from my main PC is failing, might be the reason why I couldn't make sense of the problem if only one is the cause.